# What is causing my dependency issues with uWSGI?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have the following directory structure for my Dash application:

```
my-project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ app.py
│  ├─ wsgi.py
├─ venv/
├─ requirements.txt
```

with a basic app.py file setup according to the Dash documentation.

app.py

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for your data.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

After some research on the Plotly message boards, I have the following wsgi file:

```
from app import server as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

With the virtual environment activated, if I run the following two commands, the application loads up just fine in my browser:

```
python3 src/app.py
```

```
python3 src/wsgi.py
```

However, if I attempt to test my uwsgi with the following command from within the src directory within the active virtual environment,

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application
```

I get the following errors:

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import server as application
  File "./app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dash import Dash, html, dcc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I have attempted to add an **init**.py file to the src directory after some reading but that didn't seem to solve the issue. Does anyone have any insight into what I am doing wrong here or what could be causing these dependency issues?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared to be incompatible versioning: I removed my venv and re-installed it then installed dash and pandas again and was able to run everything fine.